# IBM VS.NET SE Integration & Extensions package did not load correctly

Tags: db2, visual-studio-2022, informix

VS 2022 ver 17.8.4 send me error "IBM VS.NET SE Integration & Extensions package did not load correctly "

"The problem may have been caused or by the installation of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file '..\activylog.xml'

in activitylog xml "Setsite failed for package[..]Source:IBM.Data.Tools.Extension.Common; Description: Method not found: Void Env.DTE._dte.quit()"
[image]

How to resolve this problem ?!

Comment: Exactly which version of the IBM visual studio add-in did you install, and how?

Comment: IBM Visual studio add-in is 11.5.9 ! Install normally !Everything is ok before start VS2022 and click on add connection in server tab !